# Text appears "empty", only outlines, when font-weight:bold / 700 is used

Tags: html, css, fonts

On Windows 11, on some websites, when a `font-weight: bold` or `font-weight: 700` is used, some texts are displaying weirdly, as if they were "empty", only showing outlines.
Example on [this website](https://portail.ac-lyon.fr/ext/acloe/do/candidat).

The text displays "empty", showing only an outline, when `font-weight: bold`:

[image: Screenshot of a website using font-weight:bold where the text only shows outlines]

The same problem occurs on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but not on an Android device.
My first guess is that the problem happens when the font doesn't exist in this weight.

Not only is this bad for accessibility, but I'd like to also prevent it from happening in my future developments.

Switching to a `font-weight: normal` in the developer tools makes the problem disappear:

[Font displaying normal with a `font-weight: normal`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvnL5.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. To help us help you, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Images can be shown inline using `![` markdown code. (I wanted to edit your question, but I can't. There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow right now.)